# how to activate plugin network-wide, and save setting across sites

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

I am developing a plugin, which will be used on single site, as well as multi-site.

How to make plugin active network-wide, code required.

Also, how to save settings network-wide?

Answer (score 1):

Plugins can be *activated* network-wide by using the "Network Activate" link, or by placing the Plugin's folder inside the `\wp-content\mu-plugins` directory.

For network-wide settings versus site-specific settings, I would look at how other Plugins implement such settings, such as [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).

Comment: Agreed - when in doubt, see how someone else has solved the problem and adapt it into your own code.